# How did C-3PO become Padme's Droid?

Tags: star-wars

After Anakin and Padme leave Tatooine, C-3PO appears to be in her service. I didn't think I saw either of them trade or pay Cliegg. Given the conditions on Tatooine, I'd assume they'd off him something in return for taking his droid.

Comment: Didn't you watch.. Anakin had a crush on Padme..  :)

Comment: What better way to win a girl's heart, give her an annoying droid that won't shut up. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://www.starwarz.com/tbone/index.php?categoryid=13&p2_articleid=266) has a very good summary. She acquired C-3PO in a script scene, [deleted](http://forum.blu-ray.com/showthread.php?t=141915&page=1039) from the 2nd draft of the scenario:

> INT. TATOOINE, HOMESTEAD, GARAGE - DAY
> (sc. 116, 2nd draft version; removed from 3rd draft)
>
> ...
>
> PADMÉ fixes the last piece of covering onto THREEPIO.
>
> ...
>
> OWEN
> (grinning) Well, Padmé, I think he
> should be yours from now on...
> I know that is what my
> Mom would want.

This change was likely related to changes made in-production related to who and when built C-3PO's outer coverings.